# Dreamweaver templates in Visual Studio

Tags: templates, dreamweaver

We have some classic ASP sites with Dreamweaver templates. We now want to use Visual Studio (and tfs) to maintain these sites. Is there any way to prevent the templates from being editable (or marked some other way, so that they cannot be broken)?